# Singleton class to manage running tasks in multithreaded environment in Java

Tags: java, concurrency, singleton, threadpool

I have a similar situation to that described in this question:

[Java email sending queue - fixed number of threads sending as many messages as are available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488555/java-email-sending-queue-fixed-number-of-threads-sending-as-many-messages-as-a)

In that I have a blocking queue that gets fed commands(ICommandTask extends Callable{Object}) from which a thread pool takes off and runs. The blocking queue provides thread synchronization and isolation between calling thread and executing thread. Different objects throughout the program can submit ICommandTasks to the command queue which is why I've made AddTask() static.

```java
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import com.mypackage.tasks.ICommandTask;


public enum CommandQueue
{
    INSTANCE;

    private final BlockingQueue<ICommandTask> commandQueue;
    private final ExecutorService executor;

    private CommandQueue()
    {
        commandQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<ICommandTask>();
        executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    }

    public static void start()
    {
        new Thread(INSTANCE.new WaitForProducers()).start();
    }

    public static void addTask(ICommandTask command)
    {
        INSTANCE.commandQueue.add(command);
    }

    private class WaitForProducers implements Runnable
    {

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            ICommandTask command;

            while(true)
            {
                try
                {
                    command = INSTANCE.commandQueue.take();
                    executor.submit(task);

                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    // logging etc.
                }
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

In the main program during start up the Command Queue is started using the following which creates a New CommandQueue object and starts the WaitForProducers in a separate thread.

```java
CommandQueue.Start();
```

I wanted to ask whether this method of setting up a multiple producers to single executor using the singleton enum (so that different parts of the program can access), and that uses a separate thread to take off tasks from the queue and submit to a ThreadPool is a recommended way of doing what I want to achieve. Particularly in a very multithreaded environment.

So far it seems to be working ok but I plan on creating similar objects to CommandQueue to handle different types of Tasks. They will be stored in their own queues. E.g. OrderQueue, EventQueue, NegotiationQueue etc. So it needs to be somewhat scaleable and threadsafe.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Out of interest, why are you ignoring the Java naming conventions for methods? It's going to make your code significantly harder to read for other Java developers.

Comment: Hi Jon, do you mean using upper cases for method names etc? You can probably tell that I'm coming from a C# background. It's easier for me but you're right about making it harder for others. I will edit it. thanks

Comment: It seems like a lot of work for that and as you might know singletons are not always ideal, especially when it comes to testing. Why not simply change your producers to accept an executor argument in their constructor and call executor.submit(command) themselves? (in other words use the executor as a queue)

Comment: @assylias ,thanks for the suggestion. I understand what you mean now about singletons and testing. My only problem with this is that it's often the case that tasks come in bursts so having a queue helps smooth out the load to the pool. I realized that I can feed the blocking queue directly into the ThreadPoolExecutor without the need for separate thread to read the queue. I don't have to worry about RejectedExecutionExceptions then too. The singleton was more for convenience but try substituting for an instance

Comment: I got a hold of "Java Concurrency In Practice" which seemed highly recommended (I'm a fan now). It explains that the main ThreadPoolExecutors (newCachedThreadPool etc.) generated by the Executors factory have their own in-built synchronous queues so using a separate queue to store tasks with a newCachedThreadPool is totally unnecessary. Of course I could tweak the execution policy by creating a  ThreadPoolExecutor directly and use my blocking queue if I wanted to.